# Render an XML document

Tags: javascript

I have a variable with a string containing all my document like this :

```
var string = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <title>Report</title><item><title>Hello</title></item><item><title>Wo</title></item><item><title>rld</title></item>";
```

I would like to open a new page with this report properly inserted and displayed but have no idea how to. How can I do ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have this on the client or the server?

Comment: Can you fix the title? You're not really asking anything about "reports" (whatever those are) but instead asking how to get the browser to render an XML document that you have in a JavaScript string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the browser turn the string into an XML file like so:

```
var string = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <rss version="2.0" ><channel> <title>Report</title><item><title>Hello</title></item><item><title>Wo</title></item><item><title>rld</title></item></channel></rss>';

window.location = 'data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + string;
```

Or to open it in a new window/tab:

```
window.open('data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,' + string, '_blank');
```